# Unexpected result when destructuring object

Tags: javascript, express, destructuring

For an Express project, I'm working with the Github API for implementing OAuth in my application. I have a `_json` object, returend like this;

```
{
  login: "basvandriel",
  id: 5286260,
  email: "contact@basvandriel.nl"
}
```

Ofcourse, the object has more data in it, but I reduced it for this example.

For accessing the data, I can do `_json.email`, or any other object key, which returns the data properly. The problem is however, when trying to destruct the object by trying the following code, It returns `undefined`.

```
passport.use(new GithubStrategy({
  clientID: GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:4000/auth/github/callback"
},
async function(request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  const {
    id,
    username,
    email
  } = profile._json;

  console.log(email) //undefined
  console.log(profile._json.email) // not undefined

  // ...

}));
```

This comes from using the `passport-github2` package. I tried wrapping the `_json` object with `Object(_json)`, but had no luck either.

For a quick fix, I'm just doing this

```
const email = profile._json.email;
```

Why isn't this working? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try doing this:

```js
const {
    id: id,
    username: username,
    email: email
  } = profile._json;
```

Comment: Why would this change anything?

Comment: @Bas, If im gonna be completely honest, I don't know either. We should wait for someone who is knowledgeable on this matter, i am quite curious to learn why it works too

Comment: also, @Bas i think you mean `login` not `username` according to your example at the top